# How to secure credentials for Selenium Tests in Azdo Devops

Tags: security, azure-devops, selenium-chromedriver, credentials

We have written alot of C# .netCore 6.0 Selenium web ui tests in headless mode using this template for our URL
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("username:password:mysite.com");
Unfortunately, passing the "password" in clear text is a security violation.

In Azure DevOps, we wish to automate running selenium tests (Headless mode) and secure the credentials.

If anyone out there has a way to secure the credentials in Azure, please let me know.
We are willing to hire contractor to help us with this.

Thanks

Tom

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is actually an advertisement, looking to hire a specialist

Comment: Store credentials in a secret storage mechanism such as Azure KeyVault and integrate secret retrieval into your application via officially supported libraries.

Comment: Daniel:
Yes, we can store our credentials in Azure KeyVault, buut how do I integrate retrieval via officially supported libraries?  Which libraries are you referring to?  Can you be more specific or send me an example in C# please?   Thanks Tom

Comment: Prophet.I apologize for the hiring comment.  I won't do it again.

Answer (score 0):

**1, For pure C# code, you can get the azure key vault secret value like below:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace GetKeyVaultSecret
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string client_id = "<AAD app client id>";
            string client_secret = "<AAD app client secret>";
            string tenant_id = "<AAD app tenant id>";
            string keyVaultName = "<Your Azure key vault service name>";
            string secretName = "<your secret Name in Azure key vault>";
            string value = get_secret_value(client_id, client_secret, tenant_id, keyVaultName,secretName);
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
        //get the azure key valut secret value.
        public static string get_secret_value(string client_id, string client_secret, string tenant_id, string keyVaultName, string secretName)
        {
            var kvUri = new Uri("https://" + keyVaultName + ".vault.azure.net");
            var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret);
            var client = new SecretClient(kvUri, credential);
            var secret = client.GetSecret(secretName);
            return secret.Value.Value;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Please note in this part:

`var client = new SecretClient(kvUri, credential);`

The second parameter type is 'TokenCredential', that means all of the Subclass of 'TokenCredential' can be the parameter here. In this answer, I use client-secret-credential as the sample.

You can use any credential you like. Refer to this document, here has all of the credentials:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity?view=azure-dotnet

Client-secret-credential document is here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientsecretcredential.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#azure-identity-clientsecretcredential-ctor(system-string-system-string-system-string-azure-identity-tokencredentialoptions)

How to create the AAD app and give related permission to Azure key vault:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal

How to make some objects able to access Azure key vault:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy?tabs=azure-portal

**2, For DevOps pipeline:**

***You can use the 'lock' icon to secure the variables, pleaserefer to these official documents.***

***set variables of a pipeline directly***

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables

***set variables of variables group***

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#create-a-variable-group

After that, you can access them like other environment variables in the pipeline at runtime:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#macro-syntax-variables

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/cli/pipeline-variable-group-secret-nonsecret-variables?view=azure-devops

***Or you can reference the azure key vault from the DevOps variables group***

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#link-secrets-from-an-azure-key-vault

***Or you can get the key vault secret directly in the task***

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#create-a-new-pipeline

Comment: Dear Bowman,  Thanks for your relpy.  Much appreciated.  But regardless of how I get the password I still have to pass it in like this 
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://username:PWDFromCyberArk@mySite.com);

Comment: Dear Bowman,  
Thanks for your reply.  Much appreciated.  
But lets say I get the password from KeyVault and store it in a variable PWDFromCyberArk
I still have to pass it to in clear text to driver.Navigate().GoToUrl like this
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://username:"+PWDFromCyberArk"+"@mySite.com");
It appears as if Selenium 4.0 driver.Navigate().GoToUrl does not have any other way to secure the password.
Thoughts?
Tom

Comment: @user3540895 [set the variables in the pipeline variables definition and secure it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3Snw.png), and then using pipeline variables like this: $(yourvariable)